# Finding the 3 most occurring substrings in a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I wanted to go over the thought process of these since I am not sure how to improve this. I have a string that are separated by commas and they have reoccurring substrings and I want to find the 3 most occurring substrings.

- I was going to explode the string by commas into an array.
- Perform a substr_count in the original string for each element in the array and store it in a separate array to store the counts? (Not sure how to improve this since that would create duplicate counts for the same substring)
- Perform a max on the array to find the first, second, and third most occurring substrings.
- Return an array with the first, second, and third most occurring substrings.

I am guessing after I perform an explode, I can do a quick sort and go from there?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$result = findThreeMostOccuringStrings("apple, apple, berry, cherry, cherry, cherry, dog, dog, dog");
var_dump($result);

function findThreeMostOccuringStrings($str){
    $first = PHP_INT_MIN;
    $second = PHP_INT_MIN;
    $third = PHP_INT_MIN;

    $arr = explode(",", $str);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($str); $i++){
        $arrIdx[] = substr_count($arr[$i]);
    }

    $first = max($arrIdx);
    $arrIdx[$first] = -1;

    $second = max($arrIdx);
    $arrIdx[$first] = -1;

    $third = max($arrIdx);
    $arrIdx[$first] = -1;

    $threeMostOccuringStrings = array($first, $second, $third);

    return $threeMostOccuringStrings;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you add your code that you have tried.

Comment: can you explain what you think you mean with "substrings"? If we have an input string "cat,dog,cow" then the string "t,d" is a substring, for instance. The terms "cat", "dog" and "cow" are technically substrings but if that's what you mean then what you really mean is "this string represents a comma seprated list of terms" so `explode()` the string first, and then talk about individual elements in the array?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, by substring I mean the strings that are separated by commas in the string being passed into the function.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, yes I mean the string represents a comma separated list of terms. I wanted to explode the string, and then find out the three most frequent words.

Comment: "I have a string that are" - that doesn't make sense, it's either "I have strings that are" or "I have a string that is". That said, your subject is a bit misleading, because you effectively have a list of strings, stored in a single string with well defined separators. BTW: You might want to explode by `", "` instead of `","` and you should also consider the case that you have an empty string or less than three different strings in the list!

Answer (score 1):

If by substring you mean only the strings separated by commas and not substrings of these, use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) after explode

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an efficient way to solve substring search, the answer is a  [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), or *prefix tree*. This basically reduces the look up time to search for a substring as it creates a deterministic path for all prefixes (i.e. *a prefix tree*).

Consider the string `"A cat does not categorize its food while among other cats."` Here the substrings `categorize` and `cats` all share the same prefix of `cat`. So finding the most frequented substring in a prefix tree is easy if you count the number of `EOW` nodes stemming from each branch in the root.

Building the tree is also quite trivial.

```
function insertString($str, $trie) {
    $str = strtolower($str); // normalize case
    $node = $trie;
    foreach(str_split($str) as $letter) {
        if (!isset($node->$letter)) {
            $node->$letter = new stdClass;
        }
        $node = $node->$letter;
    }
    $node->EOW = true; // place EOL node
}

function countNodes($branch) {
    $n = 0;
    foreach($branch as $e => $node) {
        if ($node instanceof stdClass) {
            $n += countNodes($node);
        } elseif ($e === 'EOW') {
            $n++;
        }
    }
    return $n;
}

$trie = new stdClass;

$str = "A cat does not categorize its food while among other cats";

foreach(explode(' ', $str) as $word) {
    insertString($word, $trie);
}

$s = [];
foreach($trie as $n => $rootNodes) {
    $s[$n] = countNodes($rootNodes);
}
var_dump($s);
```

Which should give you...

```
array(8) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(2)
  ["c"]=>
  int(3)
  ["d"]=>
  int(1)
  ["n"]=>
  int(1)
  ["i"]=>
  int(1)
  ["f"]=>
  int(1)
  ["w"]=>
  int(1)
  ["o"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

From there you can see the root branch `c` has the highest number of substrings (which if walked match `cat`, `cats`, and `categorize`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post and the comments, you actually want to tally terms in a comma delimited list of terms, and then rank them, so: let's just do that, using an associative array for tallying and [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to sort that associative array by value, in reverse order (so that the highest counts are at the start of the array):

```
function rank($input) {
  $terms = explode(',', $input);
  $ranked = array();
  foreach($terms as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    if (!isset($ranked[$word])) {
      $ranked[$word] = 0;
    }
    $ranked[$word]++;
  }
  arsort($ranked);
  return $ranked;
}
```

So if we run that through `print_r(rank("apple, apple, berry, cherry, cherry, cherry, dog, dog, dog"))` we get:

```
Array
(
  [dog] => 3
  [cherry] => 3
  [apple] => 2
  [berry] => 1
)
```

Splendid.